# How to override flex component rendering?

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I am learning flex, but I cannot understand the phylosophy of action script overrides - assigning custom handler and calling super of that class does not produce the same result as I would suspect from normal inheritance mechanism.

For example - a chart series has property ItemRenderer - pointing with the mouse gives out the base class for ?inheritance? in my case -

```
mx.charts.chartClasses.HLOCSeriesBase.itemRenderer
```

flex help gives this:

```
itemRenderer
Type: mx.core.IFactory CSS Inheritance: No
Language Version: ActionScript 3.0  Product Version: Flex 3  Runtime Versions: Flash9, AIR 1.1 

A factory that represents the class the series will use to represent individual items on the chart. This class is instantiated once for each element in the chart. Classes used as an itemRenderer should implement the IFlexDisplayObject, ISimpleStyleClient, and IDataRenderer interfaces. The data property is assigned the chartItem that the skin instance renders.
```

so I went on and created a class witch inherits it:

```
package { // Empty package.

  import mx.charts.series.items.HLOCSeriesItem;
  import mx.core.IDataRenderer;
  import mx.core.IFlexDisplayObject;
  import mx.styles.ISimpleStyleClient;
  import flash.display.Graphics;
  import mx.charts.chartClasses.HLOCSeriesBase;
  import mx.charts.series.CandlestickSeries;

  public class CycleColorRenderer extends HLOCSeriesBase 

     implements IFlexDisplayObject, ISimpleStyleClient, IDataRenderer {

     private var _chartItem:HLOCSeriesItem;

     public function CycleColorRenderer() {
         super();
     }

     public function get data():Object {
        return _chartItem;
     }

     public function set data(value:Object):void {
        _chartItem = value as HLOCSeriesItem; 
        invalidateDisplayList();
     }


     override protected function
     updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,unscaledHeight:Number):void {
           super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
     }
}
```

MXML application rendering reasignment:

```
<mx:CandlestickSeries
dataProvider="{TICKER}"
openField="open"
highField="high"
lowField="low"
closeField="close"
displayName="TICKER"
itemRenderer="CycleColorRenderer"
>
```

It compiles OK, but running it I see an empty list and as C with some C++ programmer I fail to grasp what can go wrong here - all instances are doing what the base class would??

Maybe there is some sort of language specific concepts about inheritance?

Comment: Show us how you are using the renderer.

Comment: @Reboog711 you mean MXML property assignment? I updated my question

Comment: Yes, I guess that is what I meant. Usually in specifying a class you use the fully qualified path name; however since you're not getting a compiler error that is probably not the issue.  A review of your renderer code; it is not clear to me why your CycleColorRenderer should display differently than HLOCSeriesBase.

Comment: @Reboog711 its just empty screen, but from the updateDisplayList function I can render the bars myself without problems as info on those items is being provided correctly. One thing in particular - I am using a command line tools for compilation - mxmlc, but since it searches and compiles additional classes recursively, and doesnt produce any errors I assume it compiled the inherited class as well

Comment: I don't think your renderer class should be extending `HLOCSeriesBase`. If you look at the `CandleStickSeries` class, you'll discover that the default item renderer implementation it uses is `CandleStickItemRenderer`. I think you should take a look at that class, then extend and override it's methods to customize how things look.

Comment: @SunilD. please post your comment as answer - this worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If no item renderer is specified, the `CandleStickSeries` class by default uses a `CandleStickItemRenderer` to display each chart item (from the `CandleStickSeries.initStyles()` method):

```
csSeriesStyle.setStyle("itemRenderer", new ClassFactory(mx.charts.renderers.CandlestickItemRenderer));
```

So if you wish to customize the appearance of items for a `CandleStickSeries`, your best bet is to make your item renderer extend the `CandleStickItemRenderer` class, instead of `HLOCSeriesBase`.